# JavaScript interpreter ignores syntax error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

This short snippet of code is obviously faulty:

```
if (5 > 2) {
  console.log("5 > 2");
} else (5 < 2) {
  console.log("5 < 2");
}
```

Condition for `else` should not be specified. Execution of this code will result in `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`, as expected.

---

The problem is the fact that after a minor change (transferring the left brace to the new line), interpreter will simply ignore the syntax error.

This code:

```
if (5 > 2) {
  console.log("5 > 2");
} else (5 < 2)
{
  console.log("5 < 2");
}
```

results in this output (tested in chrome and firefox):

```
5 > 2
5 < 2
```

How is this possible? Why this `else` is not treated as a syntax error?

Comment: that looks about right. the second block `{
  console.log("5 < 2");
}` is not considered a part of the else at all ... and `( 5 < 2 )` while pointless is valid - it's like `else { ( 5<2 ) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the different interpretation is the first of the [ECMAScript Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9):

> 1. When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token (called the offending token) is encountered that is not allowed by any production of the grammar, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the offending token if one or more of the following conditions is true:
>
>    - The offending token is separated from the previous token by at least one LineTerminator.
>    - The offending token is `}`.

In your case, the offending token is `{`. In the first version of your code, neither of the bullet point conditions quoted above is true, so no semicolon is inserted, and a syntax error is raised.

In the second example of your code, there is a line terminator, as mentioned in the first condition. In that case a semicolon is inserted automatically so the parsed code really becomes this:

```
if (5 > 2) {
  console.log("5 > 2");
} else (5 < 2);
{
  console.log("5 < 2");
}
```

Now the code is valid as the opening brace that follows the semicolon is interpreted as the start of a code block that is not part of the expression that follows the `else`.

Note that even though this code now parses, it is clear that the expression in the `else` part has no effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a fast and complete answer :) I was simply shocked when the code after automatic beautification resulted in different output.

Comment: You're welcome. "Automatic Comma Insertion" is indeed one of the less appreciated syntax rules of JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that in the second case, the carriage return makes the second braced block a standalone block rather than part of the else clause where the parenthetical part is the else clause. The second case is equivalent to:

```
if (5 > 2) {
    console.log("5 > 2");
} else {
    (5 < 2)
}

{
    console.log("5 < 2");
}
```

which is just:

```
if (5 > 2) {
    console.log("5 > 2");
} else {
    false
}

console.log("5 < 2");
```

Answer (score 3):

It's all because [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion), when you transfer this brace to next line, JS engine "translates" your code to this:

```
if (5 > 2) {
  console.log("5 > 2");
} else (5 < 2);
{
  console.log("5 < 2");
}
```

Which is obviously correct, because JS allows placing stand-alone blocks.